# ES6, React and Formik Returning SetSubmitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, formik

I have a problem here on setting the `setSubmitting` function of `formik`.
Basically, I have three conditions on submit depending on the `formik.values...`

The problem is the `setSubmitting` is already firing once I click the the submit button so I think I need to return a success response on both `onCreateProduct` or `confirmOverwriteProduct` so I can successfully set the `setSubmitting` to false.

My problem is how can I do it since  both `onCreateProduct` or `confirmOverwriteProduct` is on a different component.

**Index.js**

```
const Index = () => {
  const confirmOverwriteProduct = (overwriteDataToSubmit) => {
    dispatch(
      overwriteProduct({
        data: overwriteDataToSubmit,
        callback: function (result) {
          if (result === "error") {
            setSelectedDetails({
              content: "Error overwriting!",
              status: "error",
            });
            setOpenSnackbar(true);
          }
          if (result === "success") {
            setSelectedDetails({
              content: "Overwritten successfully!",
              status: "success",
            });
            setOpenSnackbar(true);
          }
        },
      })
    );
    setConfirmationDialog(false);
  };

  const onCreateProduct = (createProductDataToSubmit) => {
    dispatch(
      createProduct({
        data: createProductDataToSubmit,
        callback: function (result) {
          if (result === "error") {
            setSelectedDetails({
              content: "Error creating product!",
              status: "error",
            });
            setOpenSnackbar(true);
          }
          if (result === "success") {
            setSelectedDetails({
              content: "Product created successfully!",
              status: "success",
            });
            setOpenSnackbar(true);
          }
        },
      })
    );
    setConfirmationDialog(false);
  };

  return <Product />;
};

export default Index;
```

**Product.js**

```
const Product = () => {


  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      productCode: product?.productCode || "",
      productImages: product?.productImages || [],
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: productSchema,
    onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      const overwriteDataToSubmit = {
        productIndex,
        imageSlotMap: values.productImages?.map(
          ({ pk = "", newContentSlot = "" }) => ({
            pk,
            slotNumber: newContentSlot,
          })
        ),
      };

      const createProductDataToSubmit = {
        productIndex,
        imageSlotMap: values.productImages?.map(
          ({ pk = "", newContentSlot = "" }) => ({
            pk,
            slotNumber: newContentSlot,
          })
        ),
        ean: values?.productCode
      };


      if (formik.values.productStatusAfterAction)
        return confirmOverwriteProduct(overwriteDataToSubmit);

      if (formik.values.productExisting)
        return confirmOverwriteProduct(overwriteDataToSubmit);

      if (!formik.values.productExisting)
        return onCreateProduct(createProductDataToSubmit);

      setSubmitting(false);
    },
  });

  return ...else.

}

export default Product
```

Comment: I believe setSubmitting is reset automatically once the onSubmit finishes, so no need to do this manually. info here: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1957#issuecomment-547779871

Comment: @jlow. We can control it though.  `setSubmitting` should fire to false only when `onCreateProduct` or `confirmOverwriteProduct` has finished.

Comment: Would it make sense for your architecture to `await` both those methods?

Comment: @jlow. I think so. Can you try writing it?

Comment: I've added 2 example. have you been able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my initial answer, but you can pass `setSubmitting` to each method:

```
const Product = ({ confirmOverwriteProduct, onCreateProduct }) => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      if (values.productStatusAfterAction || values.productExisting)
        confirmOverwriteProduct(values, setSubmitting);

      if (!values.productExisting)
        onCreateProduct(values, setSubmitting);
    },
  });
}
```

You can then execute your operations and manually set `setSubmitting(false)`.

```
const onCreateProduct(values, setSubmitting) => {
   console.log(values);
   setSubmitting(false);
}

const confirmOverwriteProduct(values, setSubmitting) => {
   console.log(values);
   setSubmitting(false);
}
```

You can find an example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-gq7bib?file=/index.js)

Comment: You mention that you use React, why do you instantiate `const formik = useFormik({ ... })` instead of using it as a component?

Comment: It doesn't set the `isSubmitting` to true though

Comment: Good point. I'm still investigating the auto setting of `setSubmitting` but in the meantime i've updated my answer.

Comment: I can not see that question

Comment: For your other question I would use `reduce`.  I've added an answer to your question.

Comment: @Joseph, are you a recruiter?

Comment: No I'm not. Why?

Comment: You're posting fun questions that are very diverse. This made me think that they are not questions that you encounter in your daily work. Whats the reason for  you posting them?

Answer (score 0):

When you return a Promise you don't have to explicitly reset `isSubmitting()`

```
const Parent = () => {
  const simpleTimeoutPromise = () =>
    new Promise((res) => {
      setTimeout(() => res("result"), 1000);
    });

  return (
    <Child simpleTimeoutPromise={simpleTimeoutPromise} />
  );
};

const Child = ({ simpleTimeoutPromise }) => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ input: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values) => simpleTimeoutPromise()}
  >
    {({ handleChange, values, isSubmitting, handleSubmit }) => (
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="input">input</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={values.input}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
     )}
  </Formik>
);
```

More details and test methods in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-setsubmitting-via-promise-qo2ub3?file=/index.js:1057-1058)